# Truth table- what is the value of the statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$(p \lor q)\rightarrow (p \land q)$ this is the statement. I know how to build the truth table from this but what does it mean when both p and q are false, what is the value of the statement?

Comment: In the case $p = q =$ FALSE, your statement is TRUE, as FALSE $\rightarrow$ FALSE is valid.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

True. Simply, because both $p$ and $q$ are false, the antecedent $p \lor q$ is false and whenever the antecedent is false, the implication statement is true.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be surprised by the fact that, by definition, false implies false. Think of the following statement.

> **If it rains then the grass gets wet; Rain $\rightarrow$ wet grass.**

- Is that implication true or false if it is actually not raining?
- Is that implication true if it is not raining and, at the same time,
  the grass is not wet.
- When can one say that the above implication is false? Only when it is raining but the grass just remains dry.